# Get mouse moving speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, mousemove

I didn't get a exact solution/calculation from stackoverflow so i created a question

```
var timestamp = null;
var mY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var now = Date.now();
    currentmY = e.pageY;



    mY = e.pageY;
    timestamp = now;
});
```

I need to get a speed value when mouse move vertical angle.

https://jsfiddle.net/58tjr9o1/

Comment: How abt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417110/3551786)

Comment: Mouse moving speed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The speed is simply the distance divided by the time it took:

```
speed = distance / time
```

The distance is `currentmY - mY`, while the time is `now - timestamp`. So in the end, you get:

```
var timestamp = 0;
var mY = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var now = Date.now();
    var currentmY = e.screenY;

    var dt = now - timestamp;
    var distance = Math.abs(currentmY - mY);
    var speed = Math.round(distance / dt * 1000);
    console.log(dt, distance, speed);
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = speed;
    
    mY = currentmY;
    timestamp = now;
});
```

Note the `* 1000`, since the timestamp is in milliseconds. The speed is here in *pixels/second*.

See [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58tjr9o1/2/).

Comment: You're missing a var before "currentmY = e.screenY"

Answer (score 1):

Following code will continuously update mouse's vertical movement speed in the span with id = "update-speed". Code is self explanatory and easy to understand, it just saved current position, previous position, current time and previous time and then calculates the speed using this formula (speed = (pos2 - pos1) / (time2 - time1).

**HTML**

```
<span id="update-speed">Update speed</span>
```

JS

```
var prev_time = new Date();
var prev_pos_y = 0;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

var now = new Date();
current_pos_y = e.pageY;

time_interval = now.getTime() - prev_time.getTime();

if(time_interval != 0)
    {
        speed = ( Math.abs(current_pos_y - prev_pos_y) / time_interval );
}
else
    speed = 0;

console.log(speed);

$('#update-speed').text(speed);


prev_time = now;
prev_pos_y = current_pos_y;


});
```