# How to get the speed of an object dragged with the mouse in P5js library

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to make a script with P5.js library that lets the user drag and drop a ball that is affected by gravity. When the user drops the ball I need to measure the speed of it.
 With that information then I'm able to act in two different ways:

1. If the ball is dropped with no speed it just falls straight down
   affected by the gravity force.
2. If the ball is dropped while moving horizontally then it needs to follow that trajectory and of course be affected by the gravity force.

How can I get the instant speed of the ball? Can someone help me?

the code is:

```
function Ball() {

    this.diameter = 50;
    this.v_speed = 0;
    this.gravity = 0.2;
    this.starty = height/2 - 100;
    this.ypos = this.starty;
    this.xpos = width/2;

    this.update = function(){

        this.v_speed = this.v_speed + this.gravity; 
        this.ypos    = this.ypos + this.v_speed;

        if (this.ypos >= height-this.diameter/2){

            this.v_speed *= -1.0; // change direction
            this.v_speed = this.v_speed*0.9; 

            if ( Math.abs(this.v_speed) < 0.5 ) {
                this.ypos = this.starty;
            }
        }
    }

    this.show = function(){
        ellipse(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.diameter);
        fill(255);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Track mouse speed with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417036/track-mouse-speed-with-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function, which checks if a XY coordinate is on the ball:

```js
this.onBall = function(x, y) {
    let dx = x - this.xpos; 
    let dy = y - this.ypos; 
    let dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx, dy*dy)
    return dist <= this.diameter/2; 
}
```

And 2 functions which start and stop dragging. The start function has set `this.v_speed = 0` and to notice the current x and y coordinate of the mouse:

```js
this.startDrag = function() {
    this.drag = true;
    this.v_speed = 0;
    this.mousex = mouseX;  
    this.mousey = mouseY;
}

this.endDrag = function() {
    this.drag = false;  
}
```

Use the [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) and [`mouseReleased()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseReleased)  event to start and stop dragging of the Ball. Dragging is stated if the mouse is on the ball:

```js
function mousePressed() {
    if ( ball.onBall(mouseX, mouseY))
        ball.startDrag();
}

function mouseReleased() {
    ball.endDrag();
}
```

In `update` you have to implement 2 cases 1 for dragging and 1 for gravity:

```js
this.update = function() {

    this.minY = this.diameter/2;
    this.maxY = height-this.diameter/2;
    this.minX = this.diameter/2;
    this.maxX = width-this.diameter/2;

    if (this.drag) {

        // ... draging

    } else {

       // ... gravity

    }
```

In case of "dragging" set the position of the ball to the mouse position. Further you have to update the initial horizontal speed `this.v_speed_x` and the vertical speed `this.v_speed`. The speed depends on the sidewards movement, immediately after the Ball is released (dragging ends):

```js
  this.xpos = Math.max(this.minX, Math.min(this.maxX, mouseX)); 
  this.ypos = mouseY; 
  this.v_speed_x = this.v_speed_x/2 + (mouseX - this.mousex);
  this.v_speed   = this.v_speed/2 + (mouseY - this.mousey);
  this.mousex = mouseX;
  this.mousey = mouseY;
```

In "gravity" case the fall and bounce has to be calculated as so far. Additional the decreasing sideward movement has to be applied:

```
// calculate gravity

this.v_speed  = this.v_speed + this.gravity; 
this.ypos = this.ypos + this.v_speed;

if (this.ypos >= this.maxY){
    this.ypos = this.maxY;
    this.v_speed *= -1.0; // change direction
    this.v_speed = this.v_speed*0.9; 
}

// the following has to be skipped if the ball is allowed to be thrown
// up to the sky (out of the screen at the top)
if (this.ypos <= this.minY){
    this.ypos = this.minY;
    this.v_speed *= -1.0;
    this.v_speed = this.v_speed*0.9;
}

// calculate side movement

this.xpos = this.xpos + this.v_speed_x;
if ( this.xpos <= this.minX){
    this.xpos = this.minX;
    this.v_speed_x *= -1;
}
if ( this.xpos >= this.maxX){
    this.xpos = this.maxX;
    this.v_speed_x *= -1;
}
this.v_speed_x = this.v_speed_x * 0.99;
```

See the example:

[image]

```js
function Ball() {
    
    this.diameter = 80;
    this.v_speed = 0;
    this.gravity = 0.2;
    this.ypos = height/2 - 100;
    this.xpos = width/2;
    this.drag = false;
    this.v_speed_x = 0;

    this.onBall = function(x, y) {
        let dx = x - this.xpos; 
        let dy = y - this.ypos; 
        let dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx, dy*dy)
        return dist <= this.diameter/2; 
    }

    this.startDrag = function() {
          this.drag = true;
          this.mousex = mouseX;
          this.mousey = mouseY;
    }

    this.endDrag = function() {
          this.drag = false;  
    }

    this.update = function() {

        this.minY = this.diameter/2;
        this.maxY = height-this.diameter/2;
        this.minX = this.diameter/2;
        this.maxX = width-this.diameter/2;

        if (this.drag) {

            this.xpos = Math.max(this.minX, Math.min(this.maxX, mouseX)); 
            this.ypos = mouseY; 
            this.v_speed_x = this.v_speed_x/2 + (mouseX - this.mousex);
            this.v_speed   = this.v_speed/2 + (mouseY - this.mousey);
            this.mousex = mouseX;
            this.mousey = mouseY;

        } else {

            // calculate gravity

            this.v_speed  = this.v_speed + this.gravity; 
            this.ypos = this.ypos + this.v_speed;
            
            if (this.ypos >= this.maxY){
                this.ypos = this.maxY;
                this.v_speed *= -1.0;
                this.v_speed = this.v_speed*0.9; 
            }
            if (/*false &&*/ this.ypos <= this.minY){
                this.ypos = this.minY;
                this.v_speed *= -1.0;
                this.v_speed = this.v_speed*0.9;
            }

            // calculate side movement

            this.xpos = this.xpos + this.v_speed_x;
            if ( this.xpos <= this.minX){
                this.xpos = this.minX;
                this.v_speed_x *= -1;
            }
            if ( this.xpos >= this.maxX){
                this.xpos = this.maxX;
                this.v_speed_x *= -1;
            }
            this.v_speed_x = this.v_speed_x * 0.99;
        }
    }

    this.show = function(){
        ellipse(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.diameter);
        fill(255);
    }
}

var ball;

function mousePressed() {
    if ( ball.onBall(mouseX, mouseY))
        ball.startDrag();
}

function mouseReleased() {
    ball.endDrag();
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    ball = new Ball();
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    ball.update();
    ball.show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.js"></script>
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/graphics-snippets/example/p5.js/p5_js_so/p5js_so_bouncing_ball_1.html)</kbd>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Why is the vertical speed not working as it should? the horizontal is fine but the vertical speed is not working well when you try to shoot the ball vertically