# Custom cursor, which follows the mouse slowly and distorts slightly when moving fast

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, custom-cursor

I came across [Jonathan](https://jonathanalpmyr.com/about/)'s website and noticed that the circle, which is behind the cursor, tracks it slowly and distorts slightly when swiping faster *(best to have a quick look at the website and move the cursor around, a bit difficult to explain)*.

I know how to create a custom cursor, but not how to **make it track the actual cursor slowly and distort slightly**.


Does anyone here have experience with this or know how to create something like this?


Here is the code (`CSS, jQuery and HTML`) for the cursor as a circle:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(80, 80, 80);
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var cursor = $(".cursor");
      
          $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
              cursor.css({
                  top: e.clientY - cursor.height() / 2,
                  left: e.clientX - cursor.width() / 2
              });
          });
      
          $(window)
              .mouseleave(function() {
                  cursor.css({
                      opacity: "0"
                  });
              })
              .mouseenter(function() {
                  cursor.css({
                      opacity: "1"
                  });
              });
      
          $(".link")
              .mouseenter(function() {
                  cursor.css({
                      transform: "scale(3.2)"
                  });
              })
              .mouseleave(function() {
                  cursor.css({
                      transform: "scale(1)"
                  });
              });
      
          $(window)
              .mousedown(function() {
                  cursor.css({
                      transform: "scale(.2)"
                  });
              })
              .mouseup(function() {
                  cursor.css({
                      transform: "scale(1)"
                  });
              });
      });
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/src/js/lib/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cursor"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

Comment: @bamtheboozle Thanks for the answer. But since the position is not set in CSS, transition-delay would not do anything (at least I think).

Comment: You need to be able to track the acceleration of the mouse movement and then update the styling of the cursor when you reach a certain threshold. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417036/track-mouse-speed-with-js

Comment: I found a [solution on CodePen](https://codepen.io/designcourse/pen/abBgxVz) regarding the slowing down of the cursor dragging. But since the other question is still open, this is not the complete solution.